# Extract the image2 from image 1

Tags: image, image-processing, image-segmentation

I want draw boundery box around the text like this  image [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79MB1.jpg)
from this [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf6wY.jpg). Can anyone suggest me a good way to do this or some algorithm or turorial anything?.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't suggested a tool, I will use ImageMagick straight at the command line as it is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows. It also has PHP, Perl, Python and .Net bindings.

So, as your background is uniform (ish) you can just use `trim` to trim it off:

```
convert image.jpg -fuzz 20% -trim result.jpg
```

[image]

Now you can add a border like this:

```
convert result.jpg -bordercolor black -border 5 result.jpg
```

[image]

Except you want the other grey background to be retained so that doesn't work for you. So, instead of actually trimming, we can ask ImageMagick where it *"would"* trim but to not actually do it like this:

```
convert image.jpg -fuzz 20% -format %@ info:
81x22+1+14
```

So, we know it would make a 81x22px box starting 1 pixel in from the left and 14 pixels down from the top, so we'll just draw a rectangle there instead of trimming it:

```
convert image.jpg -fill none -stroke black -draw "rectangle 1,14 82,36" result.jpg
```

[image]

Or, if you want the outline fatter:

```
convert image.jpg -fill none -stroke black -strokewidth 5 -draw "rectangle 1,14 82,36" result.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: m using Visual Studio

Comment: No need to write any code really. You can just type those 2 lines into a `Command Prompt` - under `Start`->`Programs`->`Accessories`.

Answer (score -1):

For a uniform background, a simple solution would be to identify all of the pixels that do not match the background color and then find the minimum and maximum indices in each axis of those pixels to define a rectangle.

For instance, if you were using Matlab, this might resemble:

1. Use 'find' to identify non-background pixels (e.g. linearIndices = find(~(image1 == background)) where background is either a hard coded set of RGB values corresponding to the background pixels or a set of RGB values identified by the mode of the image.
2. 'Find' will return linear indices rather than subscripts (i.e. bottom right corner of a 3x3 matrix is 9, not [3,3]) so use '[ind2sub](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html?searchHighlight=ind2sub)' to convert to subscripts (e.g. [I,J] = ind2sub(imageSize, linearIndices)
3. Use 'max' and 'min' to find range in x and y (e.g. rangeX = [min(I) max(I); rangeY = [min(J) max(J)])
4. Change pixels along min and max indices to border color. For instance, image1 ( rangeX(1), rangeY(1):rangeY(2) ) = boxColour (where boxColour is the RGB values of the colour you want the box to be) would draw the left border of the box. Repeat this process for the three other borders and you're done.

Of course this approach only works if the background is completely uniform. It also assumes you only want to draw a border that is one pixel thick. 
While the function recommendations correspond specifically to Matlab functions, the thought process behind those functions could likely be ported elsewhere.

Comment: actually i want to draw a boundry box around the text in image 1 like shown in image 2.

Comment: you should not ask questions in your answer - do you have a solution??

Comment: Read the links you posted. Edited my response accordingly.
Brand spankin' new to Stack Overflow so thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Meant to tag @hichris123 in that last comment